# Sniff QWebsocket Server - Client communication

Tags: c++, qt, websocket

I'm new to `QWebsocket`. I have created two applications, which use `QWebsocket` communication. Does anyone know if it is possible to capture the messages sent from `webClient` to `webServer` by another application on the same port? However, there is no way to change these 2 applications which communicate via web socket.

Answer (score 0):

no, you cannot start a second server.

```
    // setup the QWebSocketServer
    m_server = new QWebSocketServer("WebSocket app", QWebSocketServer::NonSecureMode, this);
    if (!m_server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 12345)) {
        qFatal("Failed to open web socket server, probabaly caused by an existing instance!");
        return;
    }
```